# Согласование подлежащего со сказуемым

Tags: общие-вопросы

Предложения, в которых использованы подлежащие, в которых использованы существительные, обозначающие лиц по профессии, должности:

1. О том, какая работа ведется с детьми по воспитанию экологической культуры школьников, интересно рассказал учитель биологии О. Прихунова. (Считаю, что если сказуемое находится перед подлежащим, то имя собственное не влияет на сказуемое, сказуемое согласуется со словом учитель и, соответственно, ставится в форме мужского рода).
2. Эколог администрации Т.Егорова подробно рассказала об экологической ситуации в нашем районе. (Здесь сказуемое стоит в форме женского рода, так как стоит после фамилии, которая указывает на женский род) - это понятно.

Вопрос в другом: в тексте речь о депутате - женщине, и вот такое предложение, в котором нет ее фамилии, и в каком роде должно стоят сказуемое?

Например: Депутат рассказал (или рассказала) о том, какие планы реализованы в прошедшем году.

Я утверждаю, что в муж. роде, независимо,  что депутат-женщина, здесь важно, что слово депутат муж. рода, а мне говорят, что в тексте речь о женщине и надо в жен. роде. Как быть? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Да, в первом предложении нужно "рассказала", без этого можно только формально в скобках упомянуть, кто "учитель". И ещё не хватает предлога: "**у** школьников" (= воспитывать школьников нужно так, чтобы эта культура у них была или появилась; без предлога выходит, что культура есть, но воспитывать нужно "её").

Относительно депутата. По возможности, лучше уклоняться от таких выражений. Например, если это единственная фраза, в которой важно донести, что это женщина (фамилия не так важна, главное, что 8 марта), можно сказать: "Женщина-депутат...".

Если же оставить исходную фразу, нужно оценить *контекст*. Если перед этим сообщается, что от выборного органа выступила такая-то дама, то в рассматриваемой фразе (где впервые применено наименование её должности), на мой взгляд, естественнее употребить глагол женского рода. Если же это отдельная фраза и не так важно, женщина ли на самом деле говорила (это за кадром, но выяснить это интересующиеся могут), то глагол - в мужском роде.

Answer (score 1):

> > (Считаю, что если сказуемое находится перед подлежащим, то имя собственное не влияет на сказуемое, сказуемое согласуется со словом учитель и, соответственно, ставится в форме мужского рода)

Такого правила нет.

И "с детьми" нужно убрать. Дальше же есть *школьники*!

Comment: А я такое правило нашла. Оно звучит так:
Сказуемое в книжно-письменных стилях ставится в форме мужского рода: 1) при отсутствии собственного имени; 2) если сказуемое предшествует сочетанию "рассматриваемое слово+собственное имя": Диссертант изложил интересные наблюдения. Увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Н.Петрова.